# How do I find generator matrix?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Given is matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &1  &1  &0  &1  &0  &1 \\ 
 1&0  & 0 &1  &1  &1  &1  &1 \\ 
 0&1  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0  &1 \\ 
 0&0  &1  &0  &1  &1  &1  &0 \\ 
 0&1  &1  &0  &1  &0  &1  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Find out if this matrix is valid generator matrix, if not remove some rows of matrix to get a valid generator matrix G.

Solution: Last row (5.) is remowed.

How do I know which row I should remove. I figured out only that adding first two rows we will get the last removed row.

Comment: What would this matrix generate and how?

Comment: There is more than one thing called a "generator matrix," such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_matrix) and also [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix). Which one do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

In coding theory, a [generator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_matrix) is a matrix whose rows form a basis for a linear code. Hence as long as the rows are linearly dependent and span the original row space, then it is a valid generator matrix. The answer is not unique.

After you remove the $5$-th row, check that the rows are linearly independent, if they are then you are done.

Alternatively, you can also remove the first row and check that the rows are linearly independent.

Comment: What is the easiest was to check if rows are linearly independent?

Comment: A general method can be to tranpose the matrix and obtain the RREF. The columns that corresponds to pivot columns are linearly independent.